# Show section numbers but hide the section from table of context

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

When I use `\section*{Introduction}` it hides the section from the table of context, but it also removes the numbering (i.e. it shows `Introduction` instead of `1. Introduction`). How do I keep the numbering while removing the section from the table fo context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tocdepth` counter controls what is shown in the ToC.

```
% sectocprob.tex SE 572919
\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} % only chapters and above in ToC
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```